# Multiple maximums in an interval

Tags: python, list, numpy, scipy

I think what I'm trying to do should be theoretically simple but I just can't figure out what to do. BTW before I begin I should preface with that I'm only allowing myself to use `scipy` and `numpy`. (So more importantly I'm *not* allowed to use `pandas`)

I have this [csv list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/no3sg.jpg) with the column names `'Latitude','Longitude','Time','Quantity'` (just a snippet the list is huge with a bunch of years) and what I'm trying to do is *for each year find the biggest latitude*. I'm having trouble separating the biggest element for each year. Here's my code for separating the columns

```
def read_file(x):
    # Reads the file and returns the 4 columns of datapoints as lists.
    data=np.genfromtxt(x, delimiter=',',usecols=range(4),dtype=None,unpack=True,names=True,encoding=None)
    date,time=np.genfromtxt(data['Time'],delimiter='T',dtype=None,unpack=True,encoding=None)
    year,month,day=np.genfromtxt(date,delimiter='-',dtype=None,unpack=True)
    return year,data['Latitude'] 
# I'm just returning the important things for now
# but the plan is to use all of the data for later tasks
```

The plan is to create another function that looks for whenever the current element is the same as the previous:

```
def max_per_year(x):
   year,lat=read_file(x)
   for i in range(len(year):
      if year[i]==year[i-1]:
```

and here's where I just can't figure out how to make it look through the previous `i`s until it's different again.

Comment: why not just use `max(lat)` instead of the for loop?

Comment: Because then I only get the maximum lat? I want the maximum lat *for each year*, to clarify, the 'Time' column is formatted like this "YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.000000Z" (Don't ask me why), I've exctracted the years into it's own array which just gives me a list with a lot of repeating years, and I've made another array with equal dimension for lat (I could combine these if it would help solve my problem) that corresponds to the lat of that date.

Comment: You could use a dictionary where the year is the key and value is the current max and then as you iterate through in your for loop simply check if the current value for the given year is greater than the stored value in the dictionary. Then after the loop return the dictionary.

Comment: [this](https://imgur.com/a/4ygwOeC) was my attempt, which as you can see from max(lat) for some reason doesn't work, I actually can't figure out why though? 
Edit: ok I now fully realize that the elif statement needs rework, I'm just getting duplicate years this way, but either way, the top one in my eyes *should work* but doesn't?

Comment: When you do `year,lat=read_file(x)`, what are the values of `year` and `lat`? I mean what are their types and meaning? It looks like both are numpy arrays. So is `year[i]` a year, like `1999`, and `lat[i]` the "lat" for that year? Will the same year appear multiple times in the `year`? I assume so since you are looking for a maximum. I ask all this because an alternative solution to @Fermi-4's answer below is to partition the "lat" values for each year. Then you can just use `max()` directly on each separate list of "lat" values.

Comment: All your assumptions are correct, what would be a clean way to partition then? I think this is closer in method to how I was trying to approach this problem but ran into a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets think about what this code is doing for a second...

```
def max_per_year(x):
    latdic={}
    year,lat=read_file(x)
    for i in range(len(year)):
        if year[i]==year[i-1]:
            if float(lat[i]) >=float(lat[i-1]):
                latdic[str(year[i])]=lat[i]
        elif year[i]!=year[i-1]:
            latdic[str(year[i])]=lat[i]
    return latdic, max(lat)
```

Looking at this condition in particular: `if float(lat[i]) >=float(lat[i-1])` - what this will do is it will evaluate each lat with the previous lat and replace the current max if it is greater.

So if I have an array `[10, 1, 2]` then this logic would return 2 as max number when what you need is 10. What you need to do is compare to the `current max` and not the previous index.

Also, you can drop the year comparisons entirely as it is just a key into a key value pair.

And think about this - what will `[i-1]` evaluate to when you are at the beginning of the array?

Try something like this:

```
def max_per_year(x):
    latdic={}
    year,lat=read_file(x)
    for i in range(len(year)):
        # at least one entry exist for year[i]
        if year[i] in latdic:
            # an entry exists, now check if current entry is less than lat[i]
            if latdic[year[i]] < lat[i]:
                latdic[year[i]]=lat[i]
        # no entry for year[i] key
        else:
            latdic[year[i]]=lat[i]
    return latdic
```

Comment: it did not evaluate to false, it gave me  `if latdic[year[i]]:
KeyError: 2021 ` But otherwise this makes so much more sense than my code! thank you for the help, but how do I resolve the first entry problem?

Comment: Yes you are right - I updated the answer to correctly check if the key exists.

Comment: Thank you so much! The problem is solved! Although I must admit I'm confused on why chaging `if lat[year[i]:` to `if year[i] in latdic:` fixed the check how are these not the same?

Comment: No problem. That was my fault - reciting here from memory and just got the syntax wrong.